# flutter for loop return first id only how to fix

Tags: flutter

**dart file**

```
 List<Widget> getplans() {
    List<Widget> plans = planController.plansList
        .map((e) {
          var index = e.selectSubCategory.length;
          for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            var subcategorName = e.selectSubCategory[i].subcategorName;
            var details = e.selectSubCategory[i].details;

            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(subcategorName),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  width: 350,
                  height: 200,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 10,
                  right: 20,
                  left: 20,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 140,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(details),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: 150,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Get.to(() => FormsScreen(), arguments: e.id);
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                'SELECT',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        })
        .cast<Widget>()
        .toList();

    return plans;
  }
}
```

**api response**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category 1",
        "select_sub_category": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "Sucategory 1",
                "details": "Sucategory 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "subcategor_name": "Sucategory 1.1",
                "details": "Sucategory 1.1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**here select_sub_category contain 2 data**

```
 {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "Sucategory 1",
                "details": "Sucategory 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "subcategor_name": "Sucategory 1.1",
                "details": "Sucategory 1.1"
            }
```

**but the output return only**

```
{
               "id": 1,
               "subcategor_name": "Sucategory 1",
               "details": "Sucategory 1"
           }
```

**details only but i want to get all data how to fix this **

**here select_sub_category contain 2 data id:1,id:3 but the out put return only id:1 details ony but i want to get all data how to fix this ****here select_sub_category contain 2 data id:1,id:3 but the out put return only id:1 details ony but i want to get all data how to fix this **

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'return' statement, the loop is broken. That's why you can't get to the ones after the first statement. I made an example for you, it should work correctly.

```dart
List<Widget> getplans() {
  List<Widget> result = [];

  for (final plan in planController.plansList) {
    for (final category in plan.selectSubCategory) {
      final subCategoryName = category.subcategorName;
      final details = category.details;

      result.add(
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(subCategoryName),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              width: 350,
              height: 200,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              right: 20,
              left: 20,
              child: Container(
                height: 140,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(details),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: 150,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Get.to(() => FormsScreen(), arguments: e.id);
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'SELECT',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: its working thanks you